# HTC Desire HD ....... DEAD?

Tags: htc

Can anyone help me please. I have a HTC Desire HD Sim Unlocked.

I cant charge the phone. when the USB lead is inserted in to the charging socket no LED lights up.

I cant switch on the phone.

Basically the phone is dead !

However, when i insert the usb plug in to my phone and then my PC. It recognises the phone and makes a sound.

If i then look at Device manager i get OTHER DEVICES > QHSUSB_DLOAD.  This is with a yellow explanation mark.

Does anyone know what is going on here and what can I do to get my phone up and running again ?

Thanks for your help.......

Comment: Have you tried using a different charging cable?